# How to run the python code on AWS server via the android app

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, server, kivy, face-recognition

I am now about Python and AWS, I am currently doing one of my project,
that require me to develop the android app using kivy and some functions are conducted using python. However, it is quite computationally intensive, so I'm thinking about to access the AWS cloud system at first, and all my computation works will be done on AWS, and once the computation finishes, it tell the result to the android app. Can someone tell me about how to run my python code on AWS server, actually, my project is about face-recognition, and if user clicks one single button, it will connect to the cloud server, while he/she clicks the other button, it will upload the test image to the cloud server, and the computation algorithms are all on AWS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to package your Python code in an [AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/getting-started/) function and expose it through a [REST API](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/getting-started/).

The AWS SAM framework and command line will help you to easily setup that infrastructure.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-quick-start.html

It will allow you to

- scaffold your initial project (`sam init`)
- test your code locally (`sam local`)
- package your app for deployment (`sam package`)
- deploy your app to the cloud (`sam deploy`)

and even given you access to the server side logs (`sam logs`)

Pay attention to the security of your REST API to not expose it to the world, but just your customers.  See "[Controlling access to your API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-control-access-to-api.html)" for more details

Comment: I referred the link you suggested me before, and success to the example. However, it seems that this method is for the web app, but my project is about to build the android app using kivy, I am confused about how can I use SAM framework, together with lamdba function? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

While @SebatienStomarcq's answer is a good one and should work, I would like to add my 2 cents and suggest you use [S3 events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html) instead.

If you are saying that on the click of a button an image will be uploaded to the Cloud Server, I must assume you're already using S3 to store these images. If not, I highly recommend you to do it.

Once your file has landed in S3, you can capture its events (which are highly configurable, meaning you can listen to events like PUT, COPY, DELETE and many more) and seamlessly send to it a few other AWS Services, like SNS and Lambda, for example.

With that in mind, you can now configure your Lambda that will be triggered by an S3 Event to run your algorithm or even use [AWS Rekognition](https://aws.amazon.com/rekognition/) which is perfect for your use case. In case you want to have many functions triggered at once, you could also send your S3 event to a SNS topic instead and have your Lambda functions subscribe to this topic, allowing you to get parallel processing and auto scaling out of the box.